# Constructors for Structs in C++

Tags: c++

I came across the following practice question and answer while studying C++ and I do not understand it.

> Given:
>
> ```
> class B {};
>
> struct A {
>    A( B b );
> };
> ```
>
> Call the function void `test( A a, int* b=0);` with the two corresponding variables `B b, int i;`
>
> The answer is `test( b, &i );`

My question is, how is it enough to pass the necessary parameter of the constructor and not actually call it?  In my mind, the answer should have been:

```
test( A(b), &i);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This works because `A` has a single-argument constructor, which C++ uses as a [*converting constructor*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/converting_constructor):

> A constructor that is not declared with the specifier `explicit` and which can be called with a single parameter (until C++11) is called a converting constructor. Unlike explicit constructors, which are only considered during direct initialization (which includes explicit conversions such as static_cast), converting constructors are also considered during copy initialization, as part of user-defined conversion sequence.

That is why C++ can interpret `test(b, &i)` as `test(A(b), &i)`.

If you do not want this behavior, mark `A`'s constructor `explicit`.